# SQL make query from two queries

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

I have two tables in a SQL database and I have made two queries for getting the data, but now I need to merge them in one query for having a single table.

First query is:

```
SELECT  
    Costruttore.longname AS Costruttore,  
    Parti.partnr, Parti.ordernr,    
    Parti.description1, Parti.packagingquantity, Parti.quantityunit
FROM    
    tblPart AS Parti 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    tblAddress AS Costruttore ON Parti.manufacturer = Costruttore.shortname 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    tblAddress AS Fornitore ON Parti.supplier = Fornitore.shortname
WHERE
    (Parti.id = 12757)
```

The second query is:

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
    (SELECT Id, identname, val 
     FROM tblUserFreeProperty) AS SOURCETABLE
PIVOT 
    (MAX(val)
         FOR identname IN ([DSR_Mag.Gestito], 
                           [DSR_Mag.StatoProdotto], 
                           [DSR_Mag.Qta_Cassetto], 
                           [DSR_Mag.Qta_Min],
                           [DSR_Mag.UbicazioneMag],
                           [DSR_Mag.UbicazioneScaf],
                           [DSR_Mag.UbicazionePiano],
                           [DSR_Mag.UbicazioneCass])) AS PIVOTTABLE
WHERE
    id = 12757
```

I have tried with this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT Id, identname, val FROM tblUserFreeProperty) AS SOURCETABLE
        PIVOT (MAX(val)
            FOR identname In (  [DSR_Mag.Gestito], 
                                [DSR_Mag.StatoProdotto],    
                                [DSR_Mag.Qta_Cassetto], 
                                [DSR_Mag.Qta_Min],
                                [DSR_Mag.UbicazioneMag],
                                [DSR_Mag.UbicazioneScaf],
                                [DSR_Mag.UbicazionePiano],
                                [DSR_Mag.UbicazioneCass])
          ) AS PIVOTTABLE
    inner JOIN tblpart as Parti ON  PIVOTTABLE.id=Parti.id 
    where PIVOTTABLE.[DSR_Mag.Qta_Cassetto]>0
```

This works, but I can see all the properies in tblPart. If I add some properties in the main select (like the first query: Parti.partnr, Parti.ordernr,Parti.description1, Parti.packagingquantity, Parti.quantityunit I lose the results in the subquery)

I need to make a query with a subquery with the same condition `Where Parti.id=PIVOTTABLE.id`

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: [Why should I "tag my RDBMS"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) - please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: Sorry, added sql server tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved...the final query is:

```
SELECT  Parti.partnr, Parti.ordernr, Costruttore.longname AS Costruttore,
        Descrizione= IIF(CharIndex(';', description1)-1 > 0 ,(SUBSTRING(description1, (charIndex(';it_IT@', description1)+7),(charIndex(';', description1,  (charIndex(';it_IT@', description1)+7))- (charIndex(';it_IT@', description1)+7)))), Null ),
        Parti.packagingquantity,
        'UM'=   IIF(CharIndex(';', quantityunit)-1 > 0 ,( SubString(Left(quantityunit,CharIndex(';', quantityunit)-1), CharIndex('@', quantityunit)+1,LEN(quantityunit))), Null),
        'Gestito'=          Trim('?_@;' FROM PIVOTTABLE.[DSR_Mag.Gestito]),
        'Stato Prodotto'=   Trim('?_@;' FROM PIVOTTABLE.[DSR_Mag.StatoProdotto]),
        'Giacenza'=         Trim('?_@;' FROM PIVOTTABLE.[DSR_Mag.Qta_Cassetto]),
        'Quantità minima'=  Trim('?_@;' FROM PIVOTTABLE.[DSR_Mag.Qta_Min]),
        'Ubic.Magazzino'=   Trim('?_@;' FROM PIVOTTABLE.[DSR_Mag.UbicazioneMag]),
        'Ubic.Scaffale'=    Trim('?_@;' FROM PIVOTTABLE.[DSR_Mag.UbicazioneScaf]),
        'Ubic.Piano'=       Trim('?_@;' FROM PIVOTTABLE.[DSR_Mag.UbicazionePiano]),
        'Ubic.Cassetto'=    Trim('?_@;' FROM PIVOTTABLE.[DSR_Mag.UbicazioneCass])
FROM (SELECT  Id, identname, val FROM tblUserFreeProperty) AS SOURCETABLE
        PIVOT (MAX(val)
            FOR identname In (  [DSR_Mag.Gestito], 
                                [DSR_Mag.StatoProdotto],    
                                [DSR_Mag.Qta_Cassetto], 
                                [DSR_Mag.Qta_Min],
                                [DSR_Mag.UbicazioneMag],
                                [DSR_Mag.UbicazioneScaf],
                                [DSR_Mag.UbicazionePiano],
                                [DSR_Mag.UbicazioneCass])
          ) AS PIVOTTABLE INNER JOIN tblpart as Parti ON  PIVOTTABLE.id=Parti.id 
           LEFT OUTER JOIN tblAddress AS Costruttore ON Parti.manufacturer = Costruttore.shortname 
           LEFT OUTER JOIN tblAddress AS Fornitore ON Parti.supplier = Fornitore.shortname
WHERE cast(substring(PIVOTTABLE.[DSR_Mag.Qta_Cassetto], CharIndex('@', PIVOTTABLE.[DSR_Mag.Qta_Cassetto])+1,len(PIVOTTABLE.[DSR_Mag.Qta_Cassetto])-7) as int)>0
```